# React Native - Editing Flatlist but flatlist is remain unchange

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

I am trying to edit my flatlist for my project. when the subject is added into the flatlist, the the value is added through subjectInput, markInput and gradeInput state, then i want to edit the mark and grade of that particular subject using newMarkinput and newGradeInput state, i am expecting the newMarkInput and newGradeInput overwrite the current markInput and gradeInput but my current result is that the newMarkInput and newGradeInput is still as an empty array although newMarkInput and newGradeInput value is inputted.

console log result :
80 A [{"Grade": "A", "Mark": "90", "NewGrade": [""], "NewMark": [""], "Selected": true, "Subject": "Math", "id": "0.9740256550962071"}]

i have tried adding ExtraData in the flatlist but not sure if im using it correctly

but i suspected that the ones that cause this to happen maybeee the updateSubject() but im not sure how can i fix it

my state

```
const [subjectInput, setSubjectInput] = useState('');
  const [markInput, setMarkInput] = useState('');
  const [gradeInput, setGradeInput] = useState('');

  const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([]);

  const [newMarkInput, setNewMarkInput] = useState('');
  const [newGradeInput, setNewGradeInput] = useState('');
```

my addSubject()

```
const addSubject = () => {
    if (subjectInput === '' || markInput === '' || gradeInput === ''){
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please input todo');
    } else {
      const newSubject = {
        id: Math.random().toString(),
        Subject: subjectInput,
        Mark: markInput,
        Grade: gradeInput.toUpperCase(),
        Selected: false,
        NewMark: '',
        NewGrade: '',
      };
      setSubjects([...subjects,newSubject]);
      setSubjectInput('');
      setMarkInput('');
      setGradeInput('');
      setNewGradeInput('');
      setNewMarkInput('');
    }
  };
```

my function to update the subject item

```
const updateSubject = (subjectId) => {
    if (newMarkInput === '' || newGradeInput === ''){
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please fill in all boxes');
    } else {
    const newSubject = subjects.map(item => {
      if (item.id === subjectId) {
        return {...item,Selected: false, NewMark: newMarkInput, NewGrade: newGradeInput};
      }
      return item;
    }
    );
    setSubjects(newSubject);
    console.log(newMarkInput,newGradeInput, newSubject);
  }
    setNewMarkInput('');
    setNewGradeInput('');
    setShowInputBox(false);
  };
```

my flatlist

```
<FlatList
          extraData = {subjects}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 10 , paddingBottom: 100}}
          data={subjects}
          keyExtractor = { (item) => item.id.toString() }
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressItem(item.id)}>
              <View style={[styles.listItem , {backgroundColor: item?.Selected ? '#cc66ff' : '#fff'}]}>
              <View style={styles.subject}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={[styles.examText , {fontSize: 18}]}>
                {item?.Subject}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.subjectMarkGrade}>
                  <Text style={[styles.examText , {width: '50%'}]}>
                  Mark:{item?.Mark} ( {item?.Grade} )
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={[styles.examText , {width: '50%'}]}>
                  Target: <Target/>
                </Text>
                </View>

              </View>
              <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.delete ]} onPress={() => deleteSubject(item?.id)}>
                  <Icon name="remove" size={15} color={'#fff'} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>;
```

Comment: try setSubjects([...newSubject]) to update subjects after edit.

Comment: hi Aditya, i still get the same result . if i try ([ ...subjects, newSubject ]) , i will get " undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id.toString') "

Comment: maybe the data you are setting to newGradeInput, newMarkInput could can be wrong. which will pass through your validation, as you are using === for comparison. Try logging that before updating the state.